# SSL cake PHP form

Tags: ssl, cakephp

I spent the site in https, I have 2 questions, the site is redirected but is it a 301 redirect? I did not write anything in the .htaccess file, how come the site is redirected in https?
I'm afraid of dupicate content.

The problem I have is that emails do not work anymore ...
here is the code:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Security', ['blackHoleCallback' => 'forceSSL']);
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => 'manager'],
        'loginRedirect' => ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'manager'],
        'logoutRedirect' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => 'manager'],
        // 'authorize' => 'Controller'
    ]);
}

public function forceSSL()
{
    return $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->request->here);
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Security->requireSecure();
    $this->checkManager();

    $this->set('settings', Configure::read('Settings'));
}
```

Thank you

Comment: here is the solution:

public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Security', ['blackHoleCallback' => 'forceSSL']);

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
public function initialize()
{
     parent::initialize();
     $this->loadComponent('Security', ['blackHoleCallback' => 'forceSSL']);
}

public function forceSSL()
{
    return $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->request->here);
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event); 
    $this->Security->requireSecure();
    $this->Security->config('unlockedActions', ['contact']);
}
```

AND :

Change statut in Controller.php

public function redirect($url, $status = 302)

Becomes :

public function redirect($url, $status = 301)

Comment: You are not supposed to modify core files. `$status` is an argument, so simply pass `301` to it when you call the method.